# Clear all tr tags after first tr tag in the tbody table jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I like to implement a function if I click on the button so in my tbody clear all tr tags after the first tr tag.

Here my HTML example:

```
<table id="event_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>date</th>
            <th>time</th>
            <th>action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                blabla
            </td>
            <td>
                blabla
            </td>
            <td>
                blabla
            </td>
        </tr>

<!-- from here clear all tr tag -->
        <tr>
            <td>
                blubblub
            </td>
            <td>
                blubblub
            </td>
            <td>
                blubblub
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                blubblub
            </td>
            <td>
                blubblub
            </td>
            <td>
                blubblub
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

<input type="submit" class="enter">
```

Here my jQuery Code:

```
jQuery(".enter").click(function() {

    jQuery('#event_table > tbody > tr:first-child + tr').empty();

});
```

Here my jsFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/D4cx9/2/

But my example don't works correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `nth-child(n+2)` selector to target rows after the first one:

```
$('#event_table > tbody > tr:nth-child(n+2)').remove();
```

I also think you want `remove()` instead of `empty()`, otherwise markup becomes broken (since tr's have no td tags).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/D4cx9/3/

Answer (score 1):

Your selector only select the next siblind tr after the first one. If you want to select all the `tr`s after the first child use the [`~` General sibling selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators), also `empty` just empties the element, it does not remove it, use `remove` instead

```
jQuery('#event_table > tbody > tr:first-child ~ tr').empty();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D4cx9/4/

Comment: Sibling selector, very nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

I find `:first-of-type` easier to work with

```
jQuery(".enter").click(function() {
    jQuery('#event_table > tbody > tr:not(:first-of-type)').empty();        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

And also:

```
$('#event_table > tbody > tr:gt(0)').remove();
```